# Jacoco misses all coverage if @PrepareForTest is used

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock, jacoco

I've run into an interesting problem with [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) reporting 0% coverage for a class under unit test if `@PrepareForTest` is used.

Long story short, my unit test is using a combination of `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest(SomeStaticMethodClass.class)` to perform unit tests which require the mocking of static methods.  You can read these two articles I wrote on mocking static methods ([1](https://mjremijan.blogspot.com/2014/10/mocking-static-methodsconfig-for-maven.html), [2](https://mjremijan.blogspot.com/2015/01/mocking-system-void-static.html)). The mocking of the static methods works great.  The bad side effect is that when Jacoco runs the unit tests with a `@PrepareForTest` annotation, any class unit tested is ignored and the Jacoco report for that class shows 0% coverage.  I've isolated the problem specifically to the `@PrepareForTest` annotation.  I did this by creating a simple unit test of a POJO, got 100% coverage on that POJO, then added in the `@PrepareForTest` annotation on the unit test.  After adding in that annotation the Jacoco reports shows that POJO coverage at 0%.

So anyone have any thoughts on this one?

Here is some technical information:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 02:44:56-0600)

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
. . .
</plugin>


<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.18.1</version>
  . . .
</plugin>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```